# How can I change QGIS GPS tracker symbol?

Tags: qgis, symbology, gps

I may look stupid, but can't the find place where I can change GPS live tracking symbol. I use GPS tool in fieldworks with forest orthophotos and default symbol that displays my location (black circle with inner cross) is very hard to follow.

I'm using at moment QGIS 2.99.0